# Using HoldFirst at the same time as Apply

Tags: evaluation, assignment, side-effect

I have some code which `pop`s the first number from a list, displays that number, and updates the list:

```
SetAttributes[pop, HoldFirst]
pop[a_] :=With[{tmp = First[a]}, a = Rest[a]; tmp]
```

It seemed to work just fine, for example:

```
s={2,4,9}
pop[s]
```

> ```
> 2
> ```

and `s` updates to `s={4,9}`. A problem appears when I attempt to `Apply` the function `pop` to `s`:

```
s={2,4,9}
pop @@ {s}
```

*Mathematica* complains that "Lists `{2,4,9}` and `{4,9}` are not the same shape", even though the `Attributes` of `pop` are `HoldFirst`. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because `Apply`(`@@`) doesn't have a `Hold*` attribute, so `{s}` evaluates to `{{2, 4, 9}}` before going into `pop`. To resolve to problem, `Unevaluated` is your friend:

```
pop @@ Unevaluated@{s}
s
(* 2 *)
(* {4, 9} *)
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks so much! John